# Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using sinatra for my app, i replicated the exact copy from devserver1 to devserver2, but only on devserver1 is working.

I got this on my devserver2 apache error.log :

> Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)) (process 5516, thread #):

Any help is much appreciated.

FYI: I'm using rvm and ruby-1.9.2

Comment: What version of Passenger are you using?

Comment: [ pid=5516 thr=70600110 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-06-12 21:06:34.063 ]: *** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)) (process 5516, thread #<Thread:0x86a8b5c>):
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-flash-0.1.2/lib/rack/flash.rb:11:in `use'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1341:in `setup_default_middleware'

Comment: from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1327:in `build'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1321:in `new'
        from config.ru:7:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'

Comment: from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:221:in `eval'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:221:in `load_rack_app'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:156:in `block in initialize_server'

Comment: /eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:153:in `initialize_server'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'

Comment: from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'

        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'

Comment: from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
 from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'

Comment: from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
from /home/eradev2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'

Comment: Are all the gems installed? Specifically the rack-flash gem?

Comment: think so, when i run : "bundle install" it said all are installed.
main file is 'application.rb'

<pre>
`#config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'application')
run Application`
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Found out the bug. The app is accessing a remote service which has a HTTP Authentication, it cannot pass thru that so it timed-out. Now my next problem is how to make the app bypass that HTTP authentication.

Comment: Update on the bug , or on the HTTP Authentication?